# how to handle keep and discard option button when file is downloaded using selenium webdriver in c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, winium

I want to try click on keep button using selenium or app web driver in c#.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python you can use like this

```
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
obj= {'safebrowsing.enabled': 'false'}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", obj)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions)
```

You can use like this

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddUserProfilePreference("safebrowsing.enabled", true);
var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Thank you! i have one more question. can we switch winuim web driver to chrome driver?

Comment: That I dont know exactly, but my answer help please accept as answer by ticking right

Comment: yes, your answer is correct .. Thank you so much for reply.

Comment: i want to by pass OTP using selenium web driver.. can you please help.

Comment: Post the qustion I will try

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50920942/how-to-bypass-otp-verification-with-c-sharp-using-selenium?noredirect=1#comment88852923_50920942                                  Question already posted on above link. please help if u can